# Trying to create a 2 sided document in word with two scrolling text fields. 1 to read and 1 to write essay

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-teams

I am a teacher and I am trying to create a simple tool that fits within my school's existing electronic systems as an aid for students taking tests.

I am picturing a document with two pages, so it can be displayed in Word's side-by-side view. One page would have a field that is pre-loaded with articles that can be scrolled through that is not modifiable, besides scrolling. The other page would be an editable field the students can type their own essays into.

If I can use a tool like Word to do this, it would be easy to send out to students using Teams, but I don't know if this is even possible using Word.

Comment: it's a 2 page document... it becomes 2 sided when you print it, if you choose double-sided printing

Comment: This sounds like it is not at all what Word is designed to handle. This sounds like a job for a web form of some sort, or for some sort of platform that handles static and dynamic content in the same view.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically trying to create a static document with 2 boxes that will not expand. While Word might have some functionality like that, it is in general not meant for such tasks. Word is meant for dynamic text editing.

A document type that **is** meant for static content is a PDF. Therefore, I recommend you to do the following:

Get Adobe Acrobat Pro (there should be a free trial period available) or PDFXEdit. Then start a new PDF document in your desired size and insert 2 fillable text fields. Now set the characteristics of these text-fields to "multi-line", deactivate grammer check and if you want, also set a fixed font size. This is way easier than anything similar in Word and you have the benefit that your students don't need the MS Office suite, they simply need the free Adobe Acrobat Reader which is already installed on a huge amount of devices.

Comment: Yes, static is what is needed. Thank you, for your thoughtful response. I had thought about Adobe but was unsure about the collection of the finished document. I have Adobe Pro and feel comfortable creating this document. Is there a way to add a submit button that would forward the essay to my account? If so, is it costly or included within the Pro suite? Again, thank you so much.

Comment: @Educ8All Well a PDF never has the capability to send itself, but neither has Word. You will always have to attach these documents to an email and then send the email. However, you can insert a button into a PDF which can trigger the standard mailing software to open and the append the PDF automatically. But this only works if the user has a standard mailing software defined on their computer.

Answer (score 0):

To have two sub documents as scrolling you would need 1 master and 2 subs, however that is not as natural as one document with a half page as a sub document as shown here. The problem with PDF is that only plain text as annotation is scrollable and that is never consistent across all readers as it is limited by design to be used as small comments thus you would need many on a page. I have seen a whole single page written as PDF annotation, but it can cause many problems in many other readers.

[image]

The advantage is you can also print both together as a PDF if desired.
[image]